# Null Reference Exception occurs when using odata in Web API calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, iqueryable, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the following Web API controller class:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        var products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product {Id = 1, Name = "Beans"},
            new Product {Id = 2, Name = "Sausages"},
            new Product {Id = 3, Name = "Bread"}
        };

        return products.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

I am using Fiddler to make requests to it.  These work just fine:

localhost:49629/API/Product

localhost:49629/API/Product?$orderby=Name

But when I try to use filtering, such as:

localhost:49629/API/Product?$filter=Id gt 2

a null reference occurs.  There is no source code available in the debugger, so I am unsure what has gone wrong.  Can anyone help?

Comment: You "have no source code available in the debugger", but maybe you have a call stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Fiddler you need to encode the request:

localhost:49629/API/Product?$filter=Id%20gt%202